# Remove body from webhook request in strapi

Tags: javascript, strapi

I am trying to create a webhook in Strapi, but looks like strapi is sending a Body, which the api call does not want, having this error:
`{ "status": "error", "code": 400, "title": "Bad Request", "message": "The server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect.", "detail": { "error": "Method doesn't accept a body." } }`.

How could I create this webhook without sending this body?[image]

Comment: You cannot not send a body, but maybe an empty body.